# How to return last letter in ArrayList and return total number of letters entered?

Tags: java, if-statement, arraylist

I have been trying to do a question as follows:

> The program should keep prompting the user to enter a letter until the user types ‘!’, which ends the program. Each time the use enters a letter, the program should add the letter to the previous letters entered and print the result. The program should also return:
>
> - the last entered letter when ‘@’ is entered.
> - the total number of letters entered when ‘#’ is entered.

I am stuck on how to return the last entered letter and returning number of letters entered. I thought about if statements but they don't seem to be working. Here is my code so far:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class check {

static Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
static ArrayList<String> array= new ArrayList<>();

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.print("Please enter a letter: ");
    String a=input.nextLine();
    while ( !a.equals("!")) {
        array.add(a);
        for(String b : array) {
            System.out.print(b);
        }
        System.out.print("\n"+"Please enter a letter: ");
        a=input.nextLine();
    }
    // array.add(a);
    if((a.equals("#"))) {
        ArrayList.get(ArrayList.size()-1);
        for(String b : array) {
            System.out.print(b);
        }
    }
```

I know the if statement I have done is incorrect because it's giving red line under. But don't know how and what to do next.

Comment: `ArrayList.get(ArrayList.size()-1);` is incorrect, you cant use a static ArrayList this way.
use `array.get` and `array.size()`

Comment: How many letters are they entering? Could you just unset and set a variable on every key up for each letter?

Comment: You should use the variable instead of the class. Replace `ArrayList.get(ArrayList.size()-1)` by `array.get(array.size() - 1)`. Review the Java basics.

Comment: You need to be checking for the special characters inside your while loop. You should make sure they are not added to the array as well.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what your code does line by line:

while ! is not the key that is pressed, add the key that was pressed to an ArrayList of Strings called "array."  After that, print out every string in "array," and then wait for the next keypress.

If ! is pressed, the while loop doesn't occur (nothing is added to the array, nothing is printed out, there is no .nextLine()).

At this point, if that last key wasn't "#," do nothing and the program terminates.  If it was, make a static call to

```
ArrayList.get() //(this is a compilation error)
```

then make a static call to

```
ArrayList.size() - 1 //(another compilation error).
```

To fix these errors and clean the code up to make it readable, it should be written as:

```
if(a.equals("#")){ //Remove the superfluous parentheses
    array.get(array.size() - 1);
```

When you change that line, you will now be doing this:  if that last key was "#," get the last string in the array and do nothing with it (I assume you want a System.out.println() here, as doing a array.get(array.size() - 1) but not assigning it to a variable does nothing).  After doing essentially nothing, take every string in array and print it out.

The problems should be apparent if you talk out what you're code is doing like this; it can really help!  You will have to change the program a bit to accomplish what you want as well.

In my opinion what you want to do is a while loop that checks !a.equals("!") because we still want ! to end the program.  However, in the while loop you need add an if and an else if after you print out the values in the array:  the if checks to see if the key entered was a "@" and if it is, print a... the else if checks to see if the key was "#" and if it is print array.size().

That's IF you're reading the requirements for the assignment right too;  it could be that you're supposed to be doing string concatenation instead of populating an ArrayList, i.e., declare stringBuilder outside while block, and inside while block:

```
if (stringBuilder == null){
    stringBuilder = new StringBuilder(a);
}

stringBuilder.append(a);
//print stringBuilder and then print a or stringBuilder.length()
```

Comment: You said: "...doing a array.get(array.size() - 1) but not assigning it to a variable does nothing)", but how do I assign to a variable?? I am struggling with that now.

Comment: Sure, it would be:  String lastStringInArray = array.get(array.size() - 1);  You can then use lastStringInArray in a print statement like you wanted to, like System.out.println(lastStringInArray);

Comment: Not working :( This is what I did:
 while ( !a.equals("!")
            ) 
       
    {
        array.add(a);
          for(String b : array)
        {
            String lastStringInArray = array.get(array.size() - 1);
if(a.equals("#"))
System.out.println(lastStringInArray);

else
            System.out.print(b);

Comment: and it's giving a really weird output